MOD Function Returning a Remainder When There is None
I am using the MOD function to check to see if a provided price is in whole cents (IE no more than two decimal places). I am using the formula MOD(PRICE*100,1),but have run into an issue where the function is returning a remainder when there is none for the numbers 621.42, 621.43, 621.44, and 621.45. Any idea what is causing this issue or how to resolve it?
Below is the results of the function for each:


Floating-point error?

More details on ben's comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-mod-fuction-returns-non-zero-remainder-when/988ac690-b2fc-4b0c-a919-61f4f918cc24

I saw this thread, but the issue in it seems to be that they were using decimal values for the number and the divisor. I am turning my decimal number into a whole number by multiplying by 100, so this doesn't make sense to me. And why those 4 specific numbers?

Listen to BigBen, he is wise...  I've seen those exact numbers before and it's 100% a floating-point issue.  I've had this issue eat my lunch on multiple occasions and the best way to handle it is to use ROUND to enforce the precision.

Would something like TRUNC(price, desired precision) - TRUNC(price,2) = 0 an acceptable alternative?

I can propose you the solution with using of Excel's user-defined function:

You need to insert the VBA module into the project and paste there the next code:
Option Explicit

Const DecPoint = ","

Function HasPartOfCents(rng As Range) As Variant
  Dim s As String, i As Long
  s = rng.Text
  i = InStr(s, DecPoint)
  If i > 0 Then
    HasPartOfCents = i + 2 < Len(s)
    If HasPartOfCents Then
      i = Len(s) - i - 2
      HasPartOfCents = Right$(s, i) <> String$(i, "0")
    End If
  Else
    HasPartOfCents = False
  End If
End Function

This function analyzes the text representation of a number in the referenced cell. You should leave numbers as it (General format) or format cells to display e. g. 4 digits after the decimal point.
Set the appropriate decimal point in the DecPoint constant.
This method allows to avoid problems caused by floating point arithmetic.
